# Two group by tables stich another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables I need to put together.
The first table is my main transaction table where I need to get distinct transaction id numbers and company id. It has all the important keys. The transaction ids are not unique.
The second table has item info which is linked to transaction id numbers which are not unique and I need to pull items.
The third table has company info which has company id.

Now I've sold some of these with the first one through a group by id. The second through a subquery which creates unique ids and joins onto the first one.
The issue I'm having is the third one by company. I cannot seem to create a query that works in the above combinations. Any ideas?

As suggested here is my code. It works but that's because for the company I used count which doesn't give the correct number. How else can I get the company number to come out correct?

```
SELECT
    dep.ItemIDAPK,
    dep.TotalOne,
    dep.company,
    company.vendname,
    appd.ItemIDAPK,
    appd.ItemName
FROM (
    SELECT
        csi.ItemIDAPK,
        sum(f.TotalOne) as TotalOne,
        count(f.DimCurrentcompanyID) company
    FROM dbo.ReportOne F with (nolock)
    INNER JOIN dbo.DSaleItem csi with (nolock) 
        on f.DSaleItemID = csi.DSaleItemID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimCurrentcompany cv
        ON f.DimCurrentcompanyID = cv.DimCurrentcompanyID
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dat
        on f.DimDateID = dat.DimDateID
    where (
        dat.date >='2013-01-29 00:00:00.000'
        and dat.date <= '2013-01-30 00:00:00.000'
    )
    GROUP BY csi.ItemIDAPK
) as dep
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        vend.DimCurrentcompanyID,
        vend.Name vendname
    FROM dbo.DimCurrentcompany vend
) As company
    on dep.company =  company.DimCurrentcompanyID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        c2.ItemIDAPK,
        ItemName
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ItemIDAPK
        FROM dbo.dimitem AS C
    ) AS c1
    JOIN dbo.dimitem AS c2 ON c1.ItemIDAPK = c2.ItemIDAPK
) as appd
    ON dep.ItemIDAPK = appd.ItemIDAPK
```

For further information my output is the following example, I know the code executes and the companyid is incorrect as I just put it with a (count) in their to make the above code execute:

```
Current Results:

Item Number     TLS      CompanyID    Company Name    Item Number   Item Name
111111         300         303         Johnson Corp       29323      Soap


Proposed Results:


Item Number     TLS      CompanyID    Company Name    Item Number   Item Name
111111         300         29         Johnson Corp       29323      Soap
```

Comment: This question would benefit from table structure, sample data and expected results.  As is, I doubt it'll receive a meaningful answer...

Comment: thanks, I just added it now, anything that would help would be appreciated as ive spent hours doing various combinations.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to add the input and expected results - it's currently quite difficult to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried to add the output example, I hope it helps, basically the company ID is wrong but the rest of the query works as expected